# Perl Script reopens the file in the signal handler

Tags: perl, file, signals

I have this perl script:

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep);
my $fd;
sub reopen {
    open $fd, ">>", "file.log" or die $!;
}
$SIG{USR1} = \&reopen;
reopen();
while(1){
    syswrite $fd, time . " ($$): message\n";
    usleep(100000);
}
```

I reopen file handle in the signal handler. Is it safe?

Answer (score 5):

Yes<sup>[1]</sup>. Since 5.8.1, the actual signal handler simply sets a flag saying a signal was received<sup>[2]</sup>. That flag is checked between statements. System calls (e.g. `usleep`) return with error `$!{EINTR}` when interrupted by a signal, allowing the flag to be checked.

The signal will interrupt `usleep`, and `reopen` will be called before the next statement (`syswrite`<sup>[3]</sup>) is evaluated.

---

1. Well, you might want to do `local ($!, $^E);` in case the interrupted code uses these.
2. Unless you disable "safe signals".
3. Why are you using `syswrite` instead of `print`? Is it to avoid buffering? Use `$fd->autoflush(1);` to do that.

Comment: But if the loop looks like this (usleep is removed): while(1){ syswrite $fd, time . " ($$): message\n";}. The signal will interrupt syswrite. Is it safe?

Comment: Safe, yes. Again, your code will only be executed between Perl statements. Now, it could cause `syswrite` to fail with error `$!{EINTR}`.

Comment: If I set the signal handler like this: sigaction(SIGUSR1, POSIX::SigAction->new('reopen', undef, POSIX::SA_RESTART)). Might syswrite fail with error $!{EINTR}?

Comment: Don't know what that does. If you want to make sure the `syswrite` works, you can always do `1 while !syswrite(...) && $!{EINTR};`. Be sure to localise `$!` in the handler if you do.

Comment: It does a autorestart some interrupted system calls (read, write)

Comment: @drlexa Is your question answered? If not, please leave a comment what is wrong with this answer. If it is answered, please consider marking this answer as accepted. You should do this for every question you asked, so people know that they are resolved. Thank you!